# Grails property name change

Tags: grails, netbeans, grails-orm

I have an existing grails project. The domain class I will like to change the property - i.e. has 's' no 's'. But Netbeans doesn't point out which part is affected. How can I safely make the changes?

Comment: I don't think Netbean can point out the affected parts. Since Groovy is a dynamic language,its ability of refactoring support is limited. I think your best bet is searching through the project and make changes by yourself.Please correct me if I'm wrong